# Is it possible that columns list in column menu should reorder the same way i reorder the Grid Column (Kendo Grid)

Tags: kendo-ui

After reordering the columns in kendo grid....I want it to reflect everytime in columns list of column menu.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I find it difficult to follow what the _it_ in `I want it to reflect…` refers to. A more concise title would be better.

Comment: I'm no sure if I get you right, but in [this demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ogOGU) I can change the index of a column and it is reflected in the column list, in the column menu. Example: It starts with columns in this order: `Order Date, Ship Country, Ship City`. If I set `Order Date` after `Ship Country` and open the column menu, at the columns list, the order is changed as well. Is that what you meant?